# Why with auth0-angular, it never redirect me to signup page, with the flag screen_hint: signup?

Tags: angular, authentication, auth0

I am using angular auth0-angular library and try to load the signup page, but it doesn’t redirect me to the sign up page, it always redirect me to login page.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(‘toto’);
this.auth.loginWithRedirect({ screen_hint: ‘signup’});
}
```

I also read here New Universal Login Experience(https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/auth0-universal-login/new-experience) which say to put the flag screen_hint: ‘signup’.
I am using the new universal page, i even also did a console.log(config); to see if the parameter was correctly set, as you can see in the attached image, it’s correctly added, but didn’t redirect to sign up page.

Thanks for your help

Anybody has any idea ?

I tried to search information with authO-angular, but i didn't find. I also did some test, i also read the documentation in authO website, but it doesnt help me, it says to put screen_hint: 'signup', but doesnt work, i am not sure i am going to build my application with auth0, it took to much time to integrate ...

Answer (score 1):

If this is in v2 you'll need to utilize [AuthorizationParams](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/blob/master/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#introduction-of-authorizationparams). Adding `screen_hint` to `authorizationParams` should work:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(‘toto’);
this.auth.loginWithRedirect({ 
authorizationParams: {
    screen_hint: 'signup',
  }});
}
```